# MPI_Scatter is receiving wrong values

Tags: c, mpi

My goal is to take an array of 6 integers and split them among 3 processes. However, the numbers in receiveBuffer are not correct. I don't know why the three processes don't contain integers from the original array.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "mpi.h"

#define ARRAY_SIZE 6

// simple print array method
void printArray(int arr[], int size) 
{ 
    int i; 
    for (i=0; i < size; i++) 
        printf("%d ", arr[i]); 
    printf("\n"); 
} 

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int array[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int rank, numNodes;

    // fill array with random numbers and print
    for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        array[i] = rand();

    printArray(array, ARRAY_SIZE); 

    MPI_Init( &argc, &argv );
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size (MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numNodes);

    int receiveBuffer[ARRAY_SIZE/numNodes];

    if(rank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Scatter(array, ARRAY_SIZE/numNodes, MPI_INT, &receiveBuffer, 0, MPI_INT, rank, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }

    printf("ID: %d with %d items.\n", rank, ARRAY_SIZE/numNodes);
    printArray(receiveBuffer, ARRAY_SIZE/numNodes);

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

Additionally, why is the original array printing for each process? Doesn't parallelization begin after INIT?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your usage of `MPI_Scatter()`

- `MPI_Scatter()` is a collective operation, and has hence to be invoked by all the ranks of the communicator (e.g. not only rank zero)
- since you use `MPI_INT` for both send and receive datatype, the send and receive counts should be equal (e.g. use `ARRAY_SIZE/numNodes` instead of `0`)

The MPI standard does not specify what happens before `MPI_Init()`, and it is very common that `mpirun` spawns all the tasks, so they all execute the code before `MPI_Init()`. That's why `MPI_Init()` is generally invoked at the very beginning of a MPI program.